# How to wait for task to complete before repeating it

Tags: c#, task

How I can wait for task to complete before repeating it

```
List<ushort> IdsInProgress = new List<ushort>();

public async Task<string> RunMyTask(ushort Id)
{
    if (IdsInProgress.Contains(Id))
    {
        //Here Wait previous task to finish

        //and then re-run it
        return await MyTask(Id);
    }
    return await MyTask(Id);
}

public Task<string> MyTask(ushort Id)
{
    IdsInProgress.Add(Id);
    String MyString;
    //do something
    IdsInProgress.Remove(Id);
    return Task.FromResult(MyString);
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `IdsInProgress`?

Comment: Not quite related to the question, but shouldn't `MyTask` be returning a string, not a Task? Then `RunMyTask` creates a task based on `MyTask`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight List<ushort>

Comment: It needs to be synchronized then, because `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I using singletone

Comment: but that doesn't matter does it :)

Comment: @Almis singleton or not, the access to the list needs to be synchronized, otherwise multiple threads will make inconsistent modifications to it. This matters a great deal, because synchronizing concurrent access to this list is the beginning of working out a solution to your problem.

Comment: Task.Wait ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610(v=vs.110).aspx one thing for sure i agree with @dasblinenlight IdsInProgress must be synchronized

Comment: @almis: `MyTask` isn't doing any asynchronous work.

Comment: @Almis: How do you differentiate all your tasks? Do you have some unique way to get some sort of 'handle' over the task you want to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) comments about thread-safe and sync I ended up with this solution. Not sure if this is the best way.

I remove `IdsInProgress` because I don't need it anymore.

```
private readonly object obj = new object();

public Task<string> MyTask(ushort Id)
{
    lock(obj)
    {
        String MyString;
        //do something
        return Task.FromResult(MyString);
    }
}
```

Now if I run this method 100 times they would run one after the other.

Based on [luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan) comment it's better to do this like this

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public Task<string> MyTask(ushort Id)
{
    semaphore.Wait();
    String MyString;
    //do something
    semaphore.Release();
    return Task.FromResult(MyString);
}
```

Comment: Yep, this works, but it also means that if you have 100 tasks in the queue, you also have 100 threads doing nothing. You could at least use `SemaphoreSlim` - it works pretty much the same as `lock` for a case like yours, but allows you to `await semaphore.WaitAsync()`, keeping the wait asynchronous and saving up on threads.

Comment: @Luaan thank you for your idea, edit based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at the [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) interface.

The interface allows methods to be called from any thread and marshals that call to the proper thread.

As the goal is to synchronously executes tasks, the [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.invoke.aspx) method can be used to delegate and marshal the call to the thread that created this object.
Using this method ensures that the process or task is finished before returning.

Implementing this method is quite straightforward:

```
public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
{
     return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```

Typically you would use this method as followed: `invokerObj.Invoke(MyMethod)` 
Which executes MyMethod on the thread managed by the object (invokerObj) implementing the ISynchronizeInvoke interface.

The property `InvokeRequired` and the methods `BeginInvoke` & `EndInvoke`can be implemented if you also wish the possibility to asynchronously execute a delegate. A nice demonstration can be found over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12082/A-DelegateQueue-Class).

I hope this explains it a bit more.

Comment: Ok, he looks at it and does what? Explain in your answer how `ISynchronizeInvoke` would help the OP solve his problem. As of right now, this should have been a comment, not a answer.

Comment: I can't comment on other people's posts, which was why I replied it as an anwser. And I don't know if I can add more usefull information than is displayed on the linked page.

`Provides a way to synchronously or asynchronously execute a delegate.`

Which seems like the perfect interface for the scenario he described.

Comment: There is a reason we limit comments till you have [50 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Trying to work around the restriction is not the correct way to do it. Contribute to the site by posting actual answers, not comments, get 5 upvotes and you can comment anywhere. As to your response, how would he use the interface to solve his problem, post a code snipping showing how to use the interface in a way that helps the OP and I will remove the downvote (you might even get a upvote)

Comment: I've edited my response, I'm quite new to StackOverflow. I just thought I'd mention an interface that could potentially solve the OP's problems. If he had any further questions he could always comment and I'd have been happy to answer them. The best way to learn something is to try and solve it yourself first.